# C# Using DrawingVisual to draw multiple images from a MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, wpf

In the code below, I am trying to get a images from a `MediaPlayer` from different timestamps (in `clearestThumbnails`), but in my binding in the UI, I only see the images from the first timestamp. For example, when I do `Thumbnails[5]`, it will still return to me the image from the first timestamp. I don't think my binding is the issue, as my other objects appear okay.

There seems to be a problem when the `DrawingContext` tries to draw the video image from it's current position. Moreover, is it good practice to be creating new `DrawingVisual`s with every new image? Is this why I'm having this issue?

```
foreach (var k in clearestThumbnails.Keys)
    {
        player.Play();
        player.Position = clearestThumbnails[k];
        player.Pause();

        var visual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var context = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            context.DrawVideo(player, new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, 250, 200));
        }

        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(250, 200, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(visual);

        Thumbnails.Add(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you make the Play/Possition/Stop calls after calling context.DrawVideo?

Comment: @Clemens Unfortunately it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post it here in case someone will ever need the answer. It's a little rudimentary, but it works good enough for my purposes. All I needed was to put `Thread.Sleep(100);` inside the for-loop.